# Artificial vs naturalness

Tags: soft-question

I don't know if it is appropiate to ask this, but I'm a little bit confused when mathematicians say a problem is artificial or has artificial methods. That one would prefer what is natural. I quite can´t see the difference. Perhaps you can help by an example.

Comment: Can you give any examples?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, but since neither "natural" nor "artificial" have a mathematical definition, the meaning of these notions is somewhat opinion-based.
Nevertheless, let me try to give some examples to illustrate these notions.

**The missing brick**. Suppose you have a well established mathematical theory but that some conjecture would make the theory even nicer if it were true, this conjecture is usually considered a natural question. Famous examples include the missing cases of the
[Generalized Poincaré conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture) and of the [Burnside problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem). Generalizations also fit into this category. If you have a result on fields of characteristic $0$, asking whether a similar result holds for any characteristic would likely be considered a natural question.

**The appealing theory**. If you happen to have a convincing path for future research in mathematics, then the problems you encounter along this path are usually promoted to the rank of natural problems. A prominent example is [Langlands program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program).

Now, what about artificial problems? I know this will shock a lot of people, but a very famous example is [Fermat's Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem). This was at least Gauss' opinion, who wrote in 1816:

> I confess that Fermat's Last Theorem, as an isolated proposition, has
>   very little interest for me, because I could easily lay down a
>   multitude of such propositions, which one could neither prove nor
>   dispose of.

See also this comment from [Glenn H. Stevens in the Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/are-mathematicians-finall/)

> The other problem is that Fermat's claim has always felt, well,
>   marginal. It is hard to connect the Last Theorem to other parts of
>   mathematics (...)

As you can see, being isolated, not connected to other results, seems to be the characteristic of artificial questions.

P.S. To avoid a heart attack to FLT's fans, let me explain why FLT is nevertheless considered a major result in mathematics: if the problem itself was isolated, its solutions were not. Quoting again Glenn H. Stevens

> In fact, if one looks at the history of the theorem, one sees that the
>   biggest advances in working toward a proof have arisen when some
>   connection to other mathematics was found.